# Search for all potential SQL injections via sequelize in a node project

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, sequelize.js

I have seen a legacy project that is sensible to SQL injection via Sequelize raw queries. To identify the potential suspect, I searched in the whole project for:

- `.query` (source: https://sequelize.org/v5/manual/raw-queries.html)
- `.literal` (source: [https://sequelize.org/v5/class/lib/sequelize.js~Sequelize.html#static-method-literal](https://sequelize.org/v5/class/lib/sequelize.js%7ESequelize.html#static-method-literal))

Are there other ways to run SQL injection via sequelize than using `query` and `literal` methods?

Comment: check also `.fn` for functions, they can accept simple string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Sequelize.fn` can also be dangerous if we have something like this:

```
Sequelize.fn('EXECUTE_FN', 'DROP TABLE sometable;')
```